# TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to set up server side rendering with react. Whenever I access the route in which I want server side rendering working, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined`.

My router looks like this:

```
import DetailsPage from './DetailsPage.jsx';
import Home from './Home.jsx';

const routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route name="platform" path="platform" handler={Home}/>
        <Route name="details" path="platform/details/:carId" handler={DetailsPage}/>
    </Route>
);
```

The rendering code looks like this:

```
Router.run(routes, this.request.url, function (Handler) {
      var content = React.renderToString(<Handler/>);
      reactBody = render('platform/index', {htmlReactApp: content});
    });
```

This happens using react `0.13.3`.

Something tells me it is an issue with react and not react-router.

Has anybody been through this before?

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: Sounds like you are not binding `this` correctly somewhere, but you need to find out where the error was raised.

Comment: @limelights that is happening in the server. If I bootstrap the application in the client it has no issues.

Comment: The error is raised in this line `var content = React.renderToString(<Handler/>);`, in the renderToString method parameter. @David

Comment: Are you importing `App` anywhere?

Comment: No, I am declaring it in the same file. Could it be that I need to wrap App with a createFactory?

Answer (score 0):

So guys, this issue has been resolved. The problem was that the directory in which the project lives was being cached by the OS, thus the code wasn't correctly updated when I thought it was.

I solved it by deleting the directory and cloning the git repository back into the system, after a npm install, things worked smoothly again.